# Why android may do performMeasure() twice in ViewRootImpl?

Tags: android

Why android may do `performMeasure()` twice in `ViewRootImpl`?
After first `performMeasure()`, Android will check if the `lp.horizontalWeight` or the `lp.verticalWeight` was set, then it may do the second time `performMeasure()`.

Here is my question why Android doesn't check before the first time, then just do `performMeasure()` once?

```
               // Ask host how big it wants to be
                performMeasure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);

                // Implementation of weights from WindowManager.LayoutParams
                // We just grow the dimensions as needed and re-measure if
                // needs be
                int width = host.getMeasuredWidth();
                int height = host.getMeasuredHeight();
                boolean measureAgain = false;

                if (lp.horizontalWeight > 0.0f) {
                    width += (int) ((mWidth - width) * lp.horizontalWeight);
                    childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width,
                            MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                    measureAgain = true;
                }
                if (lp.verticalWeight > 0.0f) {
                    height += (int) ((mHeight - height) * lp.verticalWeight);
                    childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height,
                            MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                    measureAgain = true;
                }

                if (measureAgain) {
                    if (DEBUG_LAYOUT) Log.v(TAG,
                            "And hey let's measure once more: width=" + width
                            + " height=" + height);
                    performMeasure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);
                }
```